# Sharepoint Date conversion

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have date in sharepoint list which is "08/11/2019" but when i am getting that from list using csom query in c# then i am getting "08/12/2019" one day after date.

i have just tried c# date conversion please guide me.

```
 System.Globalization.CultureInfo objculture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
 DateTime convertedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(collListItem[i]["WK_StartDate"]), objculture));
```

i expect the same same date that is in sharepoint list if it is 8/12/2019 then i should get the same in c# result.

Comment: What is the actual value of `collListItem[i]["WK_StartDate"]`?  Does it contain timezone info?

Comment: no value of collListItem[i]["WK_StartDate"] is "08/11/2019" in sharepoint and "08/12/2019" in c#

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint store datatime as UTC format so try to convert to your local time.

CSOM:

```
ctx.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime(datetime);
```

SSOM:

[SPTimeZone.UTCToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.sptimezone.utctolocaltime?view=sharepoint-server#Microsoft_SharePoint_SPTimeZone_UTCToLocalTime_System_DateTime_)

Answer (score 0):

"Culture" as you are using it is for formatting. You have a timezone issue. SharePoint stores in UTC and your browser is displaying either your server's timezone, your Site Collection's timezone setting or your user timezone setting.